# Combining html forms and Spring MVC controllers with @PathVariable

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to parameterize or modify the action url in an HTML form to take advantage of Spring's @PathVariable annotation?

I want to do something along the lines of:

Form:

```
<form action="/coordinates/$zipCode" method="post">
    <input id="zipCode">
    <button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/coordinates/{zipCode}")
public String getCoordinates(Model m, @PathVariable("zipCode") String zipCode)
{
    //Process zipCode, just doing a dumb println here.
    System.out.println(zipCode);
    return "view";
}
```

I know that form input fields will be passed as url parameters, but I would like to have them submitted as path variables to create a bookmark-friendly (and easier to remember) URL.

Maybe I'm overthinking this and a form is not the best way to go. Maybe skip the form and do some JavaScript magic?

Anyway, I appreciate the help.

Comment: What are you attempting to do with `$zipCode`?

Comment: HTML is, well HTML. It is static and interpreted as is. If you want your form submitted in a different way you would have to resort to JavaScript and manually construct the URL. However why would you want the full form encoded in the URL when posting a form?

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to have them submitted as path variables to create a bookmark-friendly (and easier to remember) URL*

It's not bookmark friendly if you have to submit a form to get there.

I think what you are getting at is something like [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Your resource might be identified by the zip code so you first create it by sending a POST request to the `/coordinates` URL. If you want to then access this resource, you can make a GET to `/coordinates/{zipCode}`